# how can i Debug A DLL that is referenced from a project from the same solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, c++-cli

i have a winform C# project and c++/CLR dll which both are in the same solution. and i kinda have an error when i call some method from c# -> method inside c++. so i tryed creating a break point but it wont work ...is there anything u suggest me to do?

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
       at convertor.GDItoCImgConv.CreateBitmapFromCImg(CImg<float>* img)
       at ManagedCIMG.ManagedCImg.ToBitmap()
       at SampleTester.Form1.button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\serak\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ManagedCIMG\SampleTester\Form1.cs:line 40
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at SampleTester.Program.Main() in c:\Users\serak\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ManagedCIMG\SampleTester\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: You need to set mixed mode debugger in the project settings.

Comment: This is all managed code, setting a breakpoint should not be a problem.  Unless you don't actually have the source code for this DLL.  In which case you definitely should consider not using it.

Comment: which project the C# or the dll c++/clr project?

Comment: my head is hurting i've never started this project the first time....if u have time check dis out and suggest me the issue thanks!

Comment: You might want to use `.Net Reflector`. Have it installed and right click on the reference, then `Enable Debugging`. You've done.

Comment: Totally agree with @Hans Passant; not using a buggy library which you don't have the source, is a good point.

Comment: i traced manually line by line including the source code of the dll and i found out that i have to allocate a memory before doing anything to my pointer like this img=new CImg<float>;...and now it works fine.

Comment: If it works, mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, what might be, the source code for your dll on Codeplex.
http://managedcimg.codeplex.com/
Hope this helps.

Comment: lol ya tanks but that project was mine. and now the problems are gone.